# Returning a value using a cursor mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

```
DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GET_AVG$

CREATE PROCEDURE GET_AVG()

BEGIN

    DECLARE l_avg decimal;
    DECLARE iam_done int DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE avg_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT AVG(score)
        FROM score
        GROUP BY student_id
        ;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET iam_done=1;

    BEGIN
        OPEN avg_cursor;
            tbl_loop:LOOP

                        FETCH avg_cursor INTO l_avg;

                            IF iam_done = 1 THEN
                                leave tbl_loop;
                            END IF;

                        SELECT l_avg;

            END LOOP tbl_loop;
        CLOSE avg_cursor;
    END;
END$

DELIMITER ;
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

My output is not giving me the right values:

```
mysql> call get_avg();
+----------------+
| @l_avg         |
+----------------+
| 0x             |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------+
| @l_avg         |
+----------------+
| 0x             |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) ...
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Any idea why I am having a "0x" as returned value?

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abc935d4c6befa1bb8f6778aadd241f3

Comment: In shown code you execute `SELECT l_avg;`. But in shown output I see the column name equal to `@l_avg ` which means that you perform `SELECT @l_avg;`. But local variable `l_avg` defined as `DECLARE l_avg decimal;` and user-defined variable `@l_avg` declared implicitly are two different variables.

Comment: Thanks Akina. I'll think about it and to solve it.